# HP Printer -- The Encryption Credentials Have Expired

Tags: networking, mac, printer, hp, macos-ventura

I bought a new Mac, and a new HP Printer 8020, and for 6 months it will over and over not print, and display the error "The Encryption Credientials have expired". I factory reset printer, it works, I can print and scan for a month. But it keeps coming back, over and over. Using WiFi connection, not USB cable. A home user does not need this high of security, that is stupid of HP. how do I permanently remove this error forever. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A quick search brought me just a single result [don't often see that;)

[image]

Following that took me to [HP printers - 'Encryption Credentials Expired' error (macOS, iOS)](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_7345764-7345853-16) which rather irritatingly says you need a Windows computer to generate a new certificate :\

> Generate a new self-signed certificate from EWS Open EWS from a
> Windows computer, and then generate a new self-signed certificate.
>
> Use the desktop view of the EWS to generate the certificate. The
> mobile view of the EWS does not have the Certificates menu option.
>
> 1. On a Windows computer, open an internet browser, and then enter the printer’s IP address.   NOTE: For more information on how to open the
>    EWS, see [Use the HP Printer Embedded Web Server (EWS)](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_2029438-1929621-16).   The
>    printer's EWS page opens.
> 2. In the EWS page, click the Network tab.
> 3. Click the plus sign next to Advanced Settings to expand the list, and then click Certificates.
> 4. Click Configure, select Create a New Self-Signed Certificate, and then click Next.
> 5. Click Finish.
>
> [image]
>
> The printer generates a new certificate that defaults to 10 years from
> the valid date.
>
> 6. Close the EWS page.

Comment: The browser in that screenshot is clearly an instance Firefox on most certainly not on Windows. The option doesn’t appear on a mobile device but it should appear on a desktop browser on MacOS. Their instructions are just poorly written but there isn’t anything that is Windows specific to prevent it from working on macOS

Comment: @RomeoNinov - It’s cited. They have no claim. I have literally hundreds of similar answers and not a single one has ever had a copyright claim against it. I know this because I actively track all changes to my contributions

Comment: @Ramhound, AFAIK all images published here start to have Creative Common copyright (do not remember to have exception for quoted). I am not sure HP will like this?

Comment: General notes: I really don't care about them claiming copyright over an image obtainable from any printer in a user's possession. The browser is Firefox, it says so right on the top bar. Safari for Windows was deprecated over a decade ago. tbh, I don't know why it would need Windows. My own HP Printer is older & doesn't have this particular interface, but I can easily access its web interface from my Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I can confirm the option to generate the new certificate exists on other operating systems other than just Windows. You of course have to access the page which might present other issues.